# Divide a number before formatting it inside a tooltip of Recharts

Tags: reactjs, graph, format, recharts

I have this graph from recharts and it has a very long number in the tooltip:
 [image]

If I pass this property into the graph, it format the number well

`<Tooltip formatter={maskString} />`

I'm using this function and NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

```
export const maskString = (text) => {
  const hasThousandSeparator = true;
  const prefix = '$';
  return (
    <NumberFormat
      value={text}
      displayType={'text'}
      thousandSeparator={hasThousandSeparator}
      prefix={prefix}
    />
  );
};
```

The output is just what I need: 
[image]

But before formatting the number, I need to divide it by 12...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [`ReCharts`](http://recharts.org/en-US/): `Tooltip`, and [`React Number Format`](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) for more info.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yw89pjd5/) for more practical context.

```
// Number Mask.    
export const NumberMask = (value) => (
  <NumberFormat
    value={parseInt(value/12)}
    displayType="text"
    thousandSeparator=","
    prefix="$"
  />
)

// Tooltip.
<Tooltip formatter={NumberMask}/>
```